# what kind of meat is used at carving stations?

Tags: meat

If I go into a cafeteria and they have a hunk of meat on a carving board that the cafeteria is calling "roast beef"; generally what cut of meat is used? The cafeteria slices it very thin about an eighth or an inch.  the serving size is 1 to 3 slices.

I know it is not Prime rib.  it is cut too thin to be Prime rib.

Answer (score 8):

Most buffets serve "steamship round" which is whole round, or the top round--because they are relatively inexpensive.  I have no experience with the particular restaurant named.

However, the question IS vague and there is a lot of variation.  Restaurants serving prime rib at the carving station usually make it quite evident.

Answer (score 1):

My guess would be a Shoulder Clod, a decent boneless cut from the Chuck. It could literally be anything from Prime Rib to Brisket. Prime rib wouldn't need to be sliced that thin, but a tougher cut from the Chuck would benefit a lot from being sliced thinly. https://www.thespruceeats.com/chuck-roll-and-chuck-shoulder-clod-995241

Comment: Hello, Alan. Just wanted to say hi and welcome to SA!